# RSelenium - starting server in the background (without window popup)

Tags: r, docker, selenium, rselenium

I recently got a new MacBook which seems to have changed several `RSelenium` settings. I've gotten my scraping to work properly again, except when I start a server with `rsDriver`, an actual window pops up and I don't know how to stop it.

I do like having this feature because it makes it so much easier to debug, but I run several scripts in the background while working and whenever `rsDriver` gets used it becomes the desktop focus. This is very frustrating since it disrupts whatever I'm currently working on.

To start a driver, I run:

```
remDrall <- rsDriver(port = 4446L, browser = "chrome", chromever = "84.0.4147.30", verbose = F)
```

When it's completed, a chrome window pops up with the url = "data:,". I feel like it should be an easy fix (like a `silent = TRUE` param), but I've looked through the documentation and can't find anything.

Running Catalina v 10.15.4

RSelenium package is v 1.7.1

Side note, but I'm not really sure how my `rsDriver` statement is working, since the port isn't the same as my docker image. I open up my docker with `$ docker run -d -p 4567:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome`, but if I try to use `rsDriver(port = 4567L)` then it doesn't work because it says the port is already in use. So I don't even have a docker image with port 4446, but my `rsDriver` statement still works...

Answer (score 2):

Try adding:

```
extraCapabilities = list("chromeOptions" = list(args = list('--headless')))
```

as an extra argument to rsDriver.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - this would be even better if you added an explanation on what your suggeste code does, and why you recommended it. E.g. what do the different arguments do?

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you! If you don't mind me asking, how'd you even know to look this up? Even after knowing the answer, I couldn't find anything about `extraCapabilities` on any of the `rsDriver` or `RSelenium` documentation.

Comment: There is no documentation that I am aware of. Selenium WebDriver (and RSelenium) are tools for running web browsers. To avoid the window popping up you want to run the browser [headlessly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser). If you google "RSelenium headless" you will stumble across examples such as [this](https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues/138). If you hadn't heard the term "headless browser" before then you would be stuck.